# Atomic update on multiple documents in doctrine mongodb

Tags: symfony, doctrine-mongodb

I work on a project with symfony2 and doctrine-mongodb-odm.
I want to execute an atomic update on several documents with the querybuilder but I am missing something:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:MyDoc')
->update()
->field('isOpen')->set(false)
->field('isOpen')->equals(true)
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

It works but it only updates one document. I guess I should add an option like

```
array('multi' => true)
```

somewhere but I didn't find anything about that in the docs.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer by looking in the class definition. There is a method of the query builder named multiple to set this option.

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('MyBundle:MyDoc')
->update()
->multiple(true)
->field('isOpen')->set(false)
->field('isOpen')->equals(true)
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

By now using *multiple()* is deprecated. You can simply use *updateMany()* instead.

```
/**
 * Set the "multiple" option for an update query.
 *
 * @param boolean $bool
 * @return $this
 *
 * @deprecated Deprecated in version 1.4 - use updateOne or updateMany instead
 */
public function multiple($bool = true)
{
    $this->query['multiple'] = (boolean) $bool;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Change the query type to update multiple documents
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function updateMany()
{
    $this->query['type'] = Query::TYPE_UPDATE;
    $this->query['multiple'] = true;
    return $this;
}
```